# Giving focus on checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I need to know how can I focus the "box" inside the checkbox element when the user hovers the  mouse over this element. The only way I can focus the box is hovering my mouse over the box itself, but not over the text. In fact, I cannot even check the box when I click the text.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the checkbox and text in a `<label>` tag.

Ex: `<label><input name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" />My Checkbox</label>`

Comment: should be `id` not `name`, and wrapping the labels hasnt been favoriable since ~2003

Comment: @RyanB name is valid for input as it is what a server uses as the key for this form element

Comment: @RyanB - if you wrap the label around the input you don't need the for attribute.

Comment: see my update. Wrapping a label is valid but shouldn't be used, unless you really haVe to since some technologies dont recognize it

Comment: @RyanB - What are you taking about "shouldn't be used" and "some technologies don't recognize it"? What technologies don't recognize it?

Comment: @j08691 See my edit. Doing `<label><input></label>` versus `<label for="ID"></label><input id="ID">` fell out of good/best practice ~10 years ago, yes i know it is still valid. http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?813007-Implicit-explicit-or-both-for-form-labels Various assistive technologies do not

Comment: @RyanB - no, I didn't downvote you. And there is zero wrong with using  label elements to wrap inputs as it's still 100% valid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Are you not reading what i said? I acknowledge it is valid, but not a good practice...

Comment: @RyanB - yes, I read what you wrote, however the "not a good practice" is only your opinion. Cite an authoritative source that says wrapping labels around inputs is bad practice.

Comment: My opinion of 10+years in the field and working with people from W3C, but: http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=254, http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-HTML-TECHS/html.html#H44, http://usability.com.au/2008/09/accessible-forms-using-wcag-2-0/

Comment: Thanks j08691 I will consider it. You both can find an example of what I want to do at www.facebook.com, at the checkbox. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by the first line. If you use a `<label>`, this allow you to click the text, and makes it accessible for people with disabilities.

```
<input type='checkbox' id="male"><label for="male">Male</label>
```

see [WebAIM's page on accessible controls](http://webaim.org/techniques/forms/)